# How to use Traffic Variables from the traffic reports of the business catalyst

Tags: business-catalyst

I thought of implementing counter on my home page which shows the number of web page visits. My website is hosted on Adobe Business Catalyst. I can see the traffic report generated in Business Catalyst but I am not sure how to use those values and implement them in home page.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge this isn't currently possible in Business Catalyst. If BC releases APIs to access reports then this answer may change but there are not any report APIs currently available.

With that said, it may be possible to use Google Analytics to show the data you are looking to show. You can read more on doing something like that [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/articles/gdataAnalyticsCharts?hl=en).